# Aura component used twice in page

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have an aura component that's being used twice in the same layout. This component mimics related lists:
[image]
When i press "View All", i get to see a full list of the related records.

I use the same component twice, in the same page, for different records:
[image]

When i press "View All" on the second component, it shows me the list of the first component instead.

```
<a onclick="{!c.handleGoToViewAllComponent}">View All</a>

handleGoToViewAllComponent: function(component, event, helper) {
        var navService = component.find("navService");
        var pageReference = {
            type: 'standard__component',
            attributes: {
                componentName: 'c__EnhancedRelatedListViewAll',
            },
            state: {
                "c__title": component.get("v.title"),
                "c__orderBy" : component.get("v.orderBy"),
                "c__sortedDirection" : component.get("v.sortedDirection"),
                "c__minColumnWidth" : component.get("v.minColumnWidth"),
                "c__fields" : component.get("v.fields"),
                "c__sobjectApiName" : component.get("v.sobjectApiName"),
                "c__fieldSourceApiName" : component.get("v.fieldSourceApiName"),
                "c__fieldSourceType" : component.get("v.fieldSourceType"),
                "c__relationshipPointer" : component.get("v.relationshipPointer"),
                "c__orderBy" : component.get("v.orderBy"),
                "c__filterBy" : component.get("v.filterBy"),
                "c__recordId" : component.get("v.recordId"),
                "c__allowActions" : component.get("v.allowActions"),
                "c__breadcrumbs" : JSON.stringify(component.get('v.breadcrumbs'))
            }
        };
        event.preventDefault();
        navService.navigate(pageReference);
    },
```

Couldn't find a way to solve this issue, please advise.

** UPDATE **
Full code for c__EnhancedRelatedListViewAll:

markup:

```
<aura:component controller="EnhancedRelatedListController" implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable">
    <!--parameters received from EnhancedRelatedList.cmp-->
    <aura:attribute name="title" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="sortedDirection" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="minColumnWidth" type="Integer"/>
    <aura:attribute name="fields" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="sobjectApiName" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="fieldSourceApiName" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="fieldSourceType" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="relationshipPointer" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="filterBy" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="orderBy" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>
    <aura:attribute name="allowActions" type="Boolean"/>
    <aura:attribute name="breadcrumbs" type="breadcrumbsWrapper"/>

    <aura:attribute name="showSaveMode" type="boolean" default="false"/>

    <aura:attribute name="records" type="Object" />
    <aura:attribute name="columns" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recordViewMode" type="Integer" default="1"/>
    <aura:attribute name="fieldLabelsMap" type="Map"/>
    <aura:attribute name="sortedByLabel" type="String"/>

    <aura:attribute name="customActions" type="List"/>
    <aura:attribute name="columnsWithActions" type="List" access="private"/>
     
    <!--user permissions for displaying buttons-->
    <aura:attribute name="newPermissions" type="Boolean"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="editPermissions" type="Boolean"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="deletePermissions" type="Boolean"/> 

    <!--filters-->
    <aura:attribute name="ShowFilters" type="Boolean" default="false" access="global" />


    <c:EnhancedRelatedListService aura:id="service"/>
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />

    <div class="slds-page-header slds-page-header_related-list">
        <div class="slds-page-header__row">
            <div class="slds-page-header__col-title">
                <nav role="navigation" aria-label="Breadcrumbs">
                    <ol class="slds-breadcrumb slds-list_horizontal slds-wrap">
                        <li class="slds-breadcrumb__item"><a href="{!'/lightning/o/' + v.breadcrumbs.recordObjectSingular + '/list?filterName=Recent'}">{!v.breadcrumbs.recordObjectPlural}</a></li>
                        <li class="slds-breadcrumb__item"><a href="{!'/lightning/r/' + v.breadcrumbs.recordObjectSingular + '/' + v.recordId + '/view'}">{!v.breadcrumbs.recordName}</a></li>
                    </ol>
                </nav>
                <div class="slds-media">
                    <div class="slds-media__body">
                        <div class="slds-page-header__name">
                            <div class="slds-page-header__name-title">
                                <h1>
                                    <span class="slds-page-header__title slds-truncate" title="{!v.title}">{!v.title}</span>
                                </h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-page-header__col-actions">
                <div class="slds-page-header__controls">
                    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.newPermissions}">  
                        <div class="slds-page-header__control">
                            <lightning:button label="New" onclick="{!c.handleCreateRecord}"/>
                        </div>
                    </aura:if>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-page-header__row">
            <div class="slds-page-header__col-meta">
                <p class="slds-page-header__meta-text">{!v.records.length} items • sorted by {!v.sortedByLabel}</p>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-page-header__col-controls">
                <div class="slds-page-header__controls">
                    <div class="slds-page-header__control">
                        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:filterList" variant="border-filled" onclick="{!c.ToggleFilters}"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-page-header__control">
                        <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:refresh" variant="border-filled" onclick="{!c.refreshView}"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="pageBody">
        <div style="display: flex;">
            <div id="datatable">
                <lightning:datatable aura:id="table" class="related-list"
                                        columns="{!v.allowActions ? v.columnsWithActions: v.columns}"
                                        data="{! v.records }"
                                        keyField="id"
                                        hideCheckboxColumn="true"
                                        showRowNumberColumn="true"
                                        resizeColumnDisabled="false"
                                        sortedBy="{!v.orderBy}"
                                        sortedDirection="{!v.sortedDirection}"
                                        onsort="{!c.updateColumnSorting}"
                                        minColumnWidth = "{!v.minColumnWidth}"
                />
            </div>
            <aura:renderIf isTrue="{!v.ShowFilters}">
                <div class="slds-grid slds-no-flex filters">
                   
                </div>
            </aura:renderIf>
        </div>
        <footer role="contentinfo"  style="height: 60px;">
            <div class="slds-grid slds-p-around_medium" style="justify-content: center !important;">
                <aura:if isTrue="{!v.recordViewMode == 1}"> 
                    <lightning:button label="View All" onclick="{!c.handleViewAll}"/>
                </aura:if>
            </div>
        </footer>

        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.showSaveMode}">
            <div class="slds-spinner_container" style="background-color: transparent !important;">
                <div class="slds-spinner_brand slds-spinner slds-spinner_medium slds-is-relative">
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
                    <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                    <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open" style="opacity: 0.3 !important;"></div>
        </aura:if>
    </div>

    

</aura:component>
```

controller:

```
({
    init: function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        var myPageRef = cmp.get("v.pageReference");
        cmp.set("v.title", myPageRef.state.c__title);
        cmp.set("v.sortedDirection", myPageRef.state.c__sortedDirection);
        cmp.set("v.minColumnWidth", myPageRef.state.c__minColumnWidth);
        cmp.set("v.fields", myPageRef.state.c__fields);
        cmp.set("v.sobjectApiName", myPageRef.state.c__sobjectApiName);
        cmp.set("v.fieldSourceApiName", myPageRef.state.c__fieldSourceApiName);
        cmp.set("v.fieldSourceType", myPageRef.state.c__fieldSourceType);
        cmp.set("v.relationshipPointer", myPageRef.state.c__relationshipPointer);
        cmp.set("v.orderBy", myPageRef.state.c__orderBy);
        cmp.set("v.filterBy", myPageRef.state.c__filterBy);
        cmp.set("v.recordId", myPageRef.state.c__recordId);
        cmp.set("v.allowActions", myPageRef.state.c__allowActions);
        cmp.set("v.breadcrumbs", JSON.parse(myPageRef.state.c__breadcrumbs));

        cmp.set("v.recordViewMode",1);
        helper.initView(cmp, event, helper);
    },
    
    handleRowAction: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var action = event.getParam('action');
        var row = event.getParam('row');

        switch (action.name) {
            case 'edit':
                helper.editRecord(cmp, row)
                break;
            case 'delete':
                helper.removeRecord(cmp, row)
                break;
        }
    },

    handleCreateRecord : function (cmp, event, helper) {
        var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        createRecordEvent.setParams({
            "entityApiName": cmp.get("v.sobjectApiName"),
            "defaultFieldValues": {
                [cmp.get("v.relationshipPointer")] : cmp.get("v.recordId")
            }
        });
        createRecordEvent.fire();
    },  

    refreshView : function (component, event, helper) {
        $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
    },

    updateColumnSorting: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        // We use the setTimeout method here to simulate the async
        // process of the sorting data, so that user will see the
        // spinner loading when the data is being sorted.
        setTimeout(function() {
            var fieldName = event.getParam('fieldName');
            var sortDirection = event.getParam('sortDirection');
            cmp.set("v.orderBy", fieldName);
            cmp.set("v.sortedDirection", sortDirection);
            helper.sortData(cmp,event,helper,fieldName, sortDirection);
        }, 0);
    },

    handleViewAll: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        if(cmp.get("v.recordViewMode") != 0 ) {
            //cmp.set("v.showSaveMode", true);
            helper.Waiting(cmp);

            cmp.set("v.recordViewMode",0);
            helper.initView(cmp, event, helper);
        }
    },
    handleSelect: function (cmp, event) {
        // This will contain the string of the "value" attribute of the selected
        // lightning:menuItem
        var selectedMenuItemValue = event.getParam("value");
        alert("Menu item selected with value: " + selectedMenuItemValue);
    },
    ToggleFilters: function(cmp, event) {
        var newvalue = !cmp.get("v.ShowFilters");
        cmp.set("v.ShowFilters", newvalue);
        if(newvalue) {
            document.getElementById('datatable').style.width="80%";
        } else {
            document.getElementById('datatable').style.width="100%";
        }
    }
})
```

helper:

```
({
    
    initView: function (component, event, helper) {
        helper.service(component).initView(
            component.get("v.fieldSourceType"),
            component.get("v.sobjectApiName"),
            component.get("v.fieldSourceApiName"),
            $A.getCallback(function(error,cols,fields,lookups,fieldsMap) {
                if(!error) {
                    component.set('v.columns', cols);
                    component.set('v.fields', fields);
                    component.set('v.fieldLabelsMap',fieldsMap);
                    
                    helper.fetchData(component, event, helper,lookups);

                } else {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            })
        );
    },

    initColumnsWithActions: function (cmp, event, helper) {
        helper.service(cmp).initColumnsWithActions(
            cmp.get('v.customActions'),
            cmp.get('v.editPermissions'),
            cmp.get('v.deletePermissions'),
            cmp.get('v.columns'),
            $A.getCallback(function(error, columnsWithActions) {
                if(!error) {
                    cmp.set('v.columnsWithActions', columnsWithActions);
                    //cmp.set("v.showSaveMode", false);
                    helper.DoneWaiting(cmp);
                } else {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            })
        );
    },

    fetchData: function (cmp, event, helper,lookups) {
        helper.service(cmp).fetchRecords(
            cmp.get("v.recordId"),
            cmp.get("v.fields"),
            cmp.get("v.recordViewMode"),
            cmp.get("v.relationshipPointer"),
            -1,
            cmp.get("v.sobjectApiName"),
            cmp.get("v.filterBy"),
            cmp.get("v.orderBy"),
            lookups,
            null,
            $A.getCallback(function(error, records,iconName,sobjectLabel,sobjectLabelPlural,parentRelationshipApiName,numberOfRecordsForTitle,newPermissions,editPermissions,deletePermissions,breadcrumbs) {
                if(!error) {
                    cmp.set('v.records', records);
                    cmp.set('v.newPermissions', newPermissions);
                    cmp.set('v.editPermissions', editPermissions);
                    cmp.set('v.deletePermissions', deletePermissions);
                    helper.setSortedByLabelFromMap(cmp);
                    helper.initColumnsWithActions(cmp, event, helper);
                } else {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            })
        );
    },

    setSortedByLabelFromMap: function(cmp) {
        var fieldApiName = cmp.get("v.orderBy");
        var fieldMap = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(cmp.get('v.fieldLabelsMap')));
        
        cmp.set('v.sortedByLabel',fieldMap[fieldApiName]);

        if(fieldApiName == 'LastModifiedDate') {
            cmp.set('v.sortedByLabel','Last Modified Date');    
        }
    },
    sortData: function (cmp,event, helper,fieldName, sortDirection) {
        helper.service(cmp).sortData(
            cmp.get("v.records"),
            fieldName,
            sortDirection,
            $A.getCallback(function(error, data) {
                if(!error) {
                    cmp.set('v.records', data);
                    helper.setSortedByLabelFromMap(cmp);
                } else {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            })
        );
    },

    service : function(component) {
        return component.find("service");
    },

    editRecord: function (cmp, row) {
        var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:editRecord");
        createRecordEvent.setParams({
            "recordId": row.Id
        });
        createRecordEvent.fire();
    },

    removeRecord: function (cmp, row) {
        var modalBody;
        var modalFooter;
        var sobjectLabel = cmp.get('v.sobjectLabel')
        $A.createComponents([
            ["c:deleteRecordContent", { sobjectLabel: sobjectLabel }],
            ["c:deleteRecordFooter", { record: row, sobjectLabel: sobjectLabel }]
        ],
            function (components, status) {
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    modalBody = components[0];
                    modalFooter = components[1];
                    cmp.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({
                        header: "Delete " + sobjectLabel,
                        body: modalBody,
                        footer: modalFooter,
                        showCloseButton: true
                    })
                }
            }
        );
    },

    DoneWaiting: function(component) {
        var table = component.find("table");
        $A.util.removeClass(table, "working");
      },

      Waiting: function(component) {
        var table = component.find("table");
        $A.util.addClass(table, "working");
      },
})
```

** UPDATE **
After adding the following:

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action="{!c.init}"/>
```

it works, but now when i press the second component, i get this column width:
[image]

instead of
[image]

Comment: Are you storing any state or data in the helper? The helper is a singleton that's shared across all instances of the same component. If something is stored/referenced there, you could easily see the same behavior across both instances of the component.

Comment: @pchittum how do i use a state? And how is something stored in the helper?

Comment: since you have not shared your complete code,you can also try using change handler in your second component on refrence change  reinitialize the component  like  <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action="{!c.init}"/>

Comment: @Dana Griff Can you share your full code with controller and helpers?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava please see full code

Comment: @User6670 pageReference is not an attribute in the aura, can you please post a full answer?

Comment: @danagriff i meant your c__EnhancedRelatedListViewAll component

Comment: @User6670 posted

Comment: you can add the same line  <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action="{!c.init}"/> in this component   and see if changes any thing

Comment: @User6670 seems like it works, but the column width is being reset to minimum.

Comment: can you add the image of how is it coming if it will be related to the same problem we can answer it here otherwise you can ask another question

Comment: @User6670 Added, and also please post your suggestion as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a change handler to detect changes in page reference  so that whenever it changes the component can be reinitialize like this

```
<aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.pageReference}" action="{!c.init}"/>
```

about the table width you can try removing  **style="display: flex;"** from the div